# multiple resource creation in azure with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to create multiple resources in terraform?

if i want to create 3 resource groups and call them rg1, rg2, rg3 what is the syntax to do this?

I have tried the below but it doesn't work

```
  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "rg",count
  location = "west europe"
  count = "3"
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? I think you just need `name = "rg${count.index + 1}"`.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out myself. You need to use count,index as below

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "rg${count.index}"
  location = "west europe"
  count = "3"
}
```

Comment: That will give you `rg0`, `rg1`, `rg2` but yeah that's largely right.